# Excel vb macro, copy two lines, and on the third add a changing number

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I want to copy two rows which is equal. On the third row however I want to have the number 1, and the next third row I want the number 2, on the third row I want the number 3. It would look something like this:

### Text

### Bla

### 1

### Text

### Bla

### 2

### Text

### Bla

### 3

If I am to write 100 lines I want an easy way to this this obviously. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For i = 0 To 100
    Next

Comment: I changed how the outcome would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub GenerateLines()
'
' GenerateLines Macro
' 2013/10/25
'
Dim i As Long
i = 1

Dim myLineNumber As Long
myLineNumber = 1

Do
    Range("A" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Text"
    Range("A" & i + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Bla"
    Range("A" & i + 2).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = myLineNumber

    If myLineNumber = 100 Then Exit Do

    i = i + 3        
    myLineNumber = myLineNumber + 1
Loop

End Sub
```